# Call a function inside a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I have a class inside a function I need to import to another file. I can't figure out how to call it out. Conversely I've tried to pull the class out of the function but I can't get it to call into the function once it is pulled out. Either solution would be helpful to me.

Here is the function with the class PaginatedSchema2 that I want to import.

```
def PaginatedCollection2(schema):
    if schema in paginated_schema_cache2:
        return paginated_schema_cache2[schema]
        
    class PaginatedSchema2(ma.Schema):
        class Meta:
            ordered = True

        data = ma.Nested(schema, many=True)
        total = ma.Integer(dump_only=True)
        current_page = ma.Integer()
        count = ma.Integer(dump_only=True)
        last_page = ma.Integer(dump_only=True)
        firstItem = ma.Integer(dump_only=True)
        lastItem = ma.Integer(dump_only=True)
        per_page = ma.Integer()
        first_page_url = ma.String(dump_only=True)
        last_page_url = ma.String(dump_only=True)
        next_page_url = ma.String(dump_only=True)
        prev_page_url = ma.String(dump_only=True)
        
    PaginatedSchema2.__name__ = 'Paginated{}'.format(schema.__class__.__name__)
    paginated_schema_cache2[schema] = PaginatedSchema2
    return PaginatedSchema2
```

Here is the file I am trying to call the class into. PaginatedSchema2 does it import because it's inside a function.

```
#PaginatedSchema2 does not import
from api.schemas import StringPaginationSchema, PaginatedCollection, EmptySchema,\
    PaginatedCollection2, PaginatedSchema2


def paginated_response2(schema, max_limit=25, order_by=None,
                       order_direction='asc'):
    def inner(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def paginate(*args, **kwargs):
            args = list(args)
            pagination = args.pop(-1)
            select_query = f(*args, **kwargs)
            if order_by is not None:
                o = order_by.desc() if order_direction == 'desc' else order_by
                select_query = select_query.order_by(o)

            total = db.session.scalar(sqla.select(
                sqla.func.count()).select_from(select_query))

            per_page = pagination.get('per_page', max_limit)
            current_page = pagination.get('current_page')
            after = pagination.get('after')
            url = pagination.get('url')
            if per_page > max_limit:
                per_page = max_limit
            if after is not None:
                if current_page is not None or order_by is None:  # pragma: no cover
                    abort(400)
                if order_direction != 'desc':
                    order_condition = order_by > after
                    offset_condition = order_by <= after
                else:
                    order_condition = order_by < after
                    offset_condition = order_by >= after
                query = select_query.limit(per_page).filter(order_condition)
                current_page = db.session.scalar(sqla.select(
                    sqla.func.count()).select_from(select_query.filter(
                        offset_condition)))
            else:
                if current_page is None:
                    current_page = 0
                if current_page < 0 or (total > 0 and current_page >= total) or per_page <= 0:
                    abort(400)

                query = select_query.limit(per_page).offset(current_page)
            last_page = math.ceil(total/per_page)
            if (current_page == last_page or 1):
                last_item = (total % per_page) - 1
            else:
                last_item = per_page - 1

            data = db.session.scalars(query).all()
            return {'data': data,
                'total': total,
                'current_page': current_page,
                'count': len(data),
                "last_page": last_page,
                "firstItem": 0,
                "lastItem": last_item,
                'per_page': per_page,
                "first_page_url": "http://localhost:5000/api/products?search=undefined&limit=15&page=1",
                "last_page_url": "http://localhost:5000/api/products?search=undefined&limit=15&page=63",
                "next_page_url": "http://localhost:5000/api/products?search=undefined&limit=15&page=2",
                "prev_page_url": "http://localhost:5000/api/products?search=undefined&limit=15&page=1"
            }

        # wrap with APIFairy's arguments and response decorators
        #This is where I need the PaginatedSchema2 class
        return arguments(PaginatedSchema2)(response(PaginatedCollection2(
            schema))(paginate))

    return inner
```

Comment: why do you define it inside function? Define it outside function. With current code you can't import it. You can only import function `PaginatedCollection2` and execute it to get instance of class `PaginatedSchema2` - but you can import class `PaginatedSchema2` and you can't use it directly.

Comment: there is good rule to use `lower_case_names` for functions and variables, and `CamelCaseNames` only for classes - it helps to recognize class in code. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)